# how to boot and install opensolaris using USB drive

Tags: solaris, boot, usb

I have a server that does not have a CD/DVD drive..

How can opensolaris be installed using USB interface? specifically what tools/steps that need to be performed to prepare USB flash drive as install media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating a live OpenSolaris USB disk from Windows, use the following program: http://devzone.sites.pid0.org/OpenSolaris/opensolaris-liveusb-creator

If you're creating one from a unix-y environment, this should do: http://chonan-en.blog.pid0.org/2009/11/how-to-create-opensolaris-live-usb.html

You should be able to install OpenSolaris from a live CD according to OpenSolaris [documentation](http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/2009.06/getstart/explore.html).

(Disclaimer: I'm not an OpenSolaris user, so I may have missed the mark somewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this blog post can be helpful for doing this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/clayb/entry/creating_opensolaris_usb_sticks_is

Comment: @alanc Is it just a case of substituting oracle for sun in the blog links ?

Comment: @Iain - if the blog is still in place, then for most URL's, yes, blogs.sun.com is simply replaced by blogs.oracle.com.  Some former employees had their blogs deleted in the transition; some of the ones who stayed had the username changed to resolve conflicts between existing Sun & Oracle blogs with the same name when the sites merged.  If you use an http: prefix then blogs.oracle.com will auto-redirect to https:, so you can change that as well or leave it in place and rely on the redirect.

Comment: @alanc: I thought that was the case so I posted [this over on mSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141203/blogs-sun-com-is-dead) hopefully a dev will do something globally.

Answer (score 1):

This is when the install is on the Solaris machine; In order to use the USB stick as a boot media, you will need to have the OpenBoot version higher than 4.27 (when you get to the ok prompt you see the banner that tells you your Open Boot version)..
If that condition is met, you can try to use the USB stick prep by the link provided in the first response by pk. BTW, the conversion works for certain windows versions, up to XP.. I am not sure if it works with 8.1..

Answer (score 0):

Make an USB device bootable for Solaris from Windows.

Format usb FAT (not FAT32 OR NTFS)
Go to http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html an download Imageusb
install imageusb software
when open

1. choose the usb unit you want make bootable
2. SELECT THE ACTION TO BE PERFOMED. Choose option WRITE TO USB DRIVE
3. SELECT THE IMAGE. when browse to find file image choose the extension option ALL FILES to find your file with extension *.usb
4. click WRITE and wait until the process finish.

Thas it. Reboot the computer and if everything went ok you are done.
this works for me!